# Can we extend multiple objects at once using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, object, extend

```
angular.extend($scope.postConfig, $scope.channelConfig, {
        scrollTop: 0
    });
```

> Is it correct way to extend 2 objects at once?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as mentioned in the [`angular.extend` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend),

> Extends the destination object dst by copying own enumerable properties from the src object(s) to dst. You can specify multiple src objects.

So, what you have in the question is correct syntax:

```
angular.extend($scope.postConfig, $scope.channelConfig, {
    scrollTop: 0
});
```

Just make sure that first argument is the destination object which will get extended by the (multiple) source object(s) provided as next arguments.

Comment: Yeah sure. Meanwhile it would be helpful if you upvote my ques :)

Answer (score 0):

As it said in AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) :

> ### `angular.extend`
>
> Extends the destination object `dst` by copying own enumerable
>   properties from the `src` object(s) to `dst`. You **CAN SPECIFY MULTIPLE SRC
>   OBJECTS**.

**Usage:** `angular.extend(dst, src1, src2, ...);`

Your syntax is *correct*.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! It would be nice of you to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Yeah sure. Meanwhile it would be helpful if you upvote my ques :)